# Add a button to the Product page Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am using the SpreeCommerce system to build an commerce site. I would like to add a button to the product page, next to the add to cart button, that would link to a different page from every product page. I have searched through their documentation and I can't figure out where they even add their cart button.

EDIT: If it is unclear, I don't know where the code that I want to edit is. I know how edit it and what I should put, but I don't know where to put it. If it is not like other edits with spree (you just duplicate a file and make changes) then I need more help, but I don't know what file to duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) run `bundle open spree` , navigate to core/app/spree/product/show.html.erb n
2) Inspect element on your browser and find where your button goes. 
3) Override it using deface.

Here's an example:

I'm putting a button before `div#cart-form` (untested modify accordingly)

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path  => "spree/product/show",
                         :insert_before => "div#cart-form",
                         :text          => "<button name="button">Click me</button>",
                         :name          => "button_product_show")
```

Lets assume file name is button_product_show.rb

I would put this file in `app/overrides/spree/button_product_show.rb`

spree/product/show.html.erb looks like below (at least on the version I'm using):

```
<div data-hook="product_show" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <% @body_id = 'product-details' %>

  <div class="columns six alpha" data-hook="product_left_part">
    <div class="row" data-hook="product_left_part_wrap">

      <div id="product-images" data-hook="product_images">
        <div id="main-image" data-hook>
          <%= render :partial => 'image' %>
        </div>
        <div id="thumbnails" data-hook>
          <%= render :partial => 'thumbnails' %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div data-hook="product_properties">
        <%= render :partial => 'properties' %>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columns ten omega" data-hook="product_right_part">
    <div class="row" data-hook="product_right_part_wrap">

      <div id="product-description" data-hook="product_description">

        <h1 class="product-title" itemprop="name"><%= accurate_title %></h1>

        <div itemprop="description" data-hook="description">
          <%= product_description(@product) rescue t(:product_has_no_description) %>
        </div>

        <div id="cart-form" data-hook="cart_form">
          <%= render :partial => 'cart_form' %>
        </div>

      </div>

      <%= render :partial => 'taxons' %>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Further information can be found here: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html